# How to setup JPA bi-directional one to one while avoiding n+1 queries

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to debug two entities that have a bi-directional one to one relationship.
The problem is that the relationship is causing N+1 Queries to occur.
When I run `findAll()` a single query is executed for every item in my table.

Here is an example:
I have two entities

```java
package ...;
import ...;

@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Builder

@Entity
@Table(name = "tracker")
public class TrackerEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "vehicleid")
    private UUID vehicleId;

    @Column(name = "trackerid")
    private String trackerId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicleid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private VehicleEntity vehicleEntity;
}
```

```
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Builder

@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
public class VehicleEntity {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "vehiclename")
    private String vehicleName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "vehicleEntity", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private TrackerEntity trackerEntity;
}
```

When I run `vehicleRepository.findAll()` I get following debug logs:

```
2022-05-17 19:16:45.071 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select vehicleent0_.id as id1_1_0_, vehicleent0_.vehiclename as vehiclen2_1_0_ from vehicle vehicleent0_ where vehicleent0_.id=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.097 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into vehicle (vehiclename, id) values (?, ?)
2022-05-17 19:16:45.104 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select vehicleent0_.id as id1_1_0_, vehicleent0_.vehiclename as vehiclen2_1_0_ from vehicle vehicleent0_ where vehicleent0_.id=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.106 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into vehicle (vehiclename, id) values (?, ?)
2022-05-17 19:16:45.109 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select vehicleent0_.id as id1_1_0_, vehicleent0_.vehiclename as vehiclen2_1_0_ from vehicle vehicleent0_ where vehicleent0_.id=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.110 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into vehicle (vehiclename, id) values (?, ?)
2022-05-17 19:16:45.113 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select vehicleent0_.id as id1_1_0_, vehicleent0_.vehiclename as vehiclen2_1_0_ from vehicle vehicleent0_ where vehicleent0_.id=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.115 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into vehicle (vehiclename, id) values (?, ?)
2022-05-17 19:16:45.117 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select vehicleent0_.id as id1_1_0_, vehicleent0_.vehiclename as vehiclen2_1_0_ from vehicle vehicleent0_ where vehicleent0_.id=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.119 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into vehicle (vehiclename, id) values (?, ?)
2022-05-17 19:16:45.123 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select vehicleent0_.id as id1_1_0_, vehicleent0_.vehiclename as vehiclen2_1_0_ from vehicle vehicleent0_ where vehicleent0_.id=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.125 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into vehicle (vehiclename, id) values (?, ?)
2022-05-17 19:16:45.128 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select vehicleent0_.id as id1_1_0_, vehicleent0_.vehiclename as vehiclen2_1_0_ from vehicle vehicleent0_ where vehicleent0_.id=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.130 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into vehicle (vehiclename, id) values (?, ?)
2022-05-17 19:16:45.133 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select vehicleent0_.id as id1_1_0_, vehicleent0_.vehiclename as vehiclen2_1_0_ from vehicle vehicleent0_ where vehicleent0_.id=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.135 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into vehicle (vehiclename, id) values (?, ?)
2022-05-17 19:16:45.138 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select vehicleent0_.id as id1_1_0_, vehicleent0_.vehiclename as vehiclen2_1_0_ from vehicle vehicleent0_ where vehicleent0_.id=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.141 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into vehicle (vehiclename, id) values (?, ?)
2022-05-17 19:16:45.144 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select vehicleent0_.id as id1_1_0_, vehicleent0_.vehiclename as vehiclen2_1_0_ from vehicle vehicleent0_ where vehicleent0_.id=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.146 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into vehicle (vehiclename, id) values (?, ?)
2022-05-17 19:16:45.246 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select vehicleent0_.id as id1_1_, vehicleent0_.vehiclename as vehiclen2_1_ from vehicle vehicleent0_
2022-05-17 19:16:45.253 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select trackerent0_.vehicleid as vehiclei1_0_0_, trackerent0_.trackerid as trackeri2_0_0_ from tracker trackerent0_ where trackerent0_.vehicleid=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.258 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select trackerent0_.vehicleid as vehiclei1_0_0_, trackerent0_.trackerid as trackeri2_0_0_ from tracker trackerent0_ where trackerent0_.vehicleid=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.259 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select trackerent0_.vehicleid as vehiclei1_0_0_, trackerent0_.trackerid as trackeri2_0_0_ from tracker trackerent0_ where trackerent0_.vehicleid=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.261 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select trackerent0_.vehicleid as vehiclei1_0_0_, trackerent0_.trackerid as trackeri2_0_0_ from tracker trackerent0_ where trackerent0_.vehicleid=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.262 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select trackerent0_.vehicleid as vehiclei1_0_0_, trackerent0_.trackerid as trackeri2_0_0_ from tracker trackerent0_ where trackerent0_.vehicleid=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.264 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select trackerent0_.vehicleid as vehiclei1_0_0_, trackerent0_.trackerid as trackeri2_0_0_ from tracker trackerent0_ where trackerent0_.vehicleid=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.265 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select trackerent0_.vehicleid as vehiclei1_0_0_, trackerent0_.trackerid as trackeri2_0_0_ from tracker trackerent0_ where trackerent0_.vehicleid=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.267 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select trackerent0_.vehicleid as vehiclei1_0_0_, trackerent0_.trackerid as trackeri2_0_0_ from tracker trackerent0_ where trackerent0_.vehicleid=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.269 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select trackerent0_.vehicleid as vehiclei1_0_0_, trackerent0_.trackerid as trackeri2_0_0_ from tracker trackerent0_ where trackerent0_.vehicleid=?
2022-05-17 19:16:45.271 DEBUG 62639 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select trackerent0_.vehicleid as vehiclei1_0_0_, trackerent0_.trackerid as trackeri2_0_0_ from tracker trackerent0_ where trackerent0_.vehicleid=?
```

I've searched for N+1 JPA Query problems in hopes of finding a solution and most either suggested using EntityGraph or "bytecode enhancement". I've tried using entitygraph and still got n+1 queries and I don't want to use bytecode enhancement since the application has to run on a cloud as a microservice.

One more important thing is I want Trackers to be removed when their Vehicle is removed but they should not be created when a vehicle is created.

Is there any way to fix this?

I have tried using Query and join fetch:

```
public interface VehicleRepository extends JpaRepository<VehicleEntity, UUID> {

    @Override
    @Query("SELECT v FROM VehicleEntity v left outer join fetch v.trackerEntity t")
    <S extends VehicleEntity> List<S> findAll(Example<S> example);
}
```

which did not change anything, still got n+1 queries.
I have tried EntityGraph which changed nothing as well:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
@NamedEntityGraph(name="vehicleGraph", attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("trackerEntity")})
public class VehicleEntity {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "vehiclename")
    private String vehicleName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "vehicleEntity", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private TrackerEntity trackerEntity;
}
```

```
public interface VehicleRepository extends JpaRepository<VehicleEntity, UUID> {

    @Override
    @EntityGraph(value = "vehicleGraph", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    <S extends VehicleEntity> List<S> findAll(Example<S> example);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried disable eager fetching with `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`?

Comment: Yes i have tried that and it changed nothing

Comment: You've got the JoinColumn using the TrackerEntity's ID as the foreign key - this is wrong, as you have it both as a FK and as something that must be set yourself in the instance, so has two writeable mappings. You should really fix that as I don't see how you can insert a TrackerEntity and you certainly cannot change its vehicleEntity reference. But  your Query annotation is not the query being executed in the SQL you've shown. It is ignoring that query annotation and its fetch join, so you might try renaming the method to something Spring won't try to build a query for and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize this with `EntityGraph` and lazy loading. I presume `VehicleEntity` is the owning entity here. In that case make `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` and `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` should be  on the owning entity. And EntityGraph can be defined 2 ways

1. Named Entity Graph
2. AD-HOC or Unnamed Entity Graph

**Named Entity Graph:**

you can define `NamedEntityGraph` on owning class and reference it in `VehicleEntityRepository` interface

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "VehicleEntity.trackerEntity", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("trackerEntity"))
public class VehicleEntity {
}
```

VehicleEntityRepository.java

```
public interface VehicleEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<VehicleEntity, UUID> {
     @EntityGraph(value = "VehicleEntity.trackerEntity", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    List<VehicleEntity> findAll();
}
```

**AD-HOC Entity Graph:**

You don't have to define any EntityGraph annotation VehicleEntity class but can directly use it Repository interface

VehicleEntityRepository.java

```
public interface VehicleEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<VehicleEntity, UUID> {
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "trackerEntity" })
    List<VehicleEntity> findAll();
}
```

**VehicleEntity.java**

```
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Builder

@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "VehicleEntity.trackerEntity", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("trackerEntity"))
public class VehicleEntity {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "vehiclename")
    private String vehicleName;

 
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "vehicleEntity")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private TrackerEntity trackerEntity;
}
```

**TrackerEntity.java**

```
package ...;
import ...;

@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Builder

@Entity
@Table(name = "tracker")
public class TrackerEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "trackerid")
    private String trackerId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicleid", referencedColumnName = "id")
@JsonBackReference
    private VehicleEntity vehicleEntity;
}
```

You can also use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` to prevent nested fetch or infinite recursion when using Jackson.

Comment: Using those exact changes, i am still getting n+1 queries

Comment: @Alan: Why is `vehicleid` mentioned twice on TrackerEntity? You need to get rid of it or rename it to `trackerId`

Comment: You need to use `EntityGraph`. You can see more info here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph

Comment: where is vehicleid mentioned twice? it is declared once as a id and then used in joincolumn. As for EntityGraph, i did exactly that, the same way it was shown in the docs and nothing changed (see edited question). i am still getting n+1 queries

Comment: See my updated answer. This will prevent N+1 query. And Yes it's mentioned twice. `JoinColumn` creates `vehicleid` in TrackerEntity class and you already defined `vehicleid` as UUID. See your example. It would have never compiled. I updated `VehicleEntity` in my example

Comment: i have tried all the solutions you proposed post-edit, half of those queries disappeared (the ones starting with "select trackerent_..."). However the Queries starting with "select vehicleent0_..." persisted throughout all your solutions. And i even copy pasted your code to make sure

Comment: I executed the `findAll()` method, I only see one query. Share code example in Github, I can take a look.`Hibernate: select vehicleent0_.id as id1_7_0_, trackerent1_.tracker_id as tracker_1_6_1_, vehicleent0_.vehiclename as vehiclen2_7_0_, trackerent1_.vehicleid as vehiclei2_6_1_ from vehicle vehicleent0_ left outer join tracker trackerent1_ on vehicleent0_.id=trackerent1_.vehicleid`